# Li3: Find filter in parent class not triggering when child calls find()

Tags: php, lithium

This is a question on Li3 philosophy. I have a child class, trying to run `find()` on a parent class which as a filter on its `find()` but that doesn't get executed when the child calls `find()`.

I have a `Members` model extending a `Users` mode.
The `Users` model has some filters:

```
<?php
# Users.php
namespace app\models;

class Users extends \lithium\data\Model {
}

Users::applyFilter('find', function($self, $params, $chain) {
    echo __LINE__;
    return $chain->next($self, $params, $chain);
});

Users::applyFilter('save', function($self, $params, $chain) {
    echo __LINE__;
    return $chain->next($self, $params, $chain);
});
?>

<?php
# Members.php
namespace app\models;

class Members extends \app\models\Users {
}
?>
```

If I use the `Members` model in any controller and attempt to execute a `find()` or a `save()` on `Members`, the filters won't be triggered.

```
<?php
# FooController.php
namespace app\controllers;

use app\models\Members;

class FooController extends \lithium\action\Controller {
    public function bar() {
        $bar = Members::find();
        return compact('bar');
    }

    public function baz() {
        $baz = Members::create();
        $baz->save([
            'type' => 'addiction',
            'framework' => 'lithium'
        ]);
        return compact('baz');
    }
}
?>
```

I can always omit the filters in `Users` and inherit + override the `find()` and `save()` methods in the `Users` model which would cause a call on `Members::find()` to trigger `Users::find()`, for example, but what is the Li3 philosophy on doing things this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My view is that if the code in the filters are actually part of your User model, as in doing something that is related to User's business rule, then you should override the `find()` and `save()`.

And when you write a unit test for the `User` class, you can easily write test for those functions without having to rely on the filters on those functions not being cleared (which can be common during unit testing)

Filters should be reserved for cross cutting functionalities, such logging.

Comment: That makes sense when you say it that way :) Thanks for taking the time to reply.

I think I'll move things like password hashing, setting created/updated time fields, etc. to the overridden save() method as opposed to a filter.